# Create mount points automatically in /mnt, even though / is read-only

Tags: mount, readonly, root-filesystem

I have a requirement of changing my root partition to Readonly.

After changing `/` to readonly in `/etc/fstab`, I rebooted the system.

Mount points of USB devices is `/mnt`.

But after above changes USB folder is not creating under `/mnt/sdXX` because of Read only Root partition.

Can I get any work around for this requirement please..

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is mount /mnt on tmpfs. In `/etc/fstab`

```
tmpfs   /mnt   tmpfs size=1M 0 0
```

That really should solve your initial problem (but I'm sure you'll have more to come!)

Answer (score 0):

If this is home work ......

Just create all mount points while the system is read write. Then mount read only.

`mount -o remount,rw /`
`mkdir /mnt`
`reboot`

should do the trick.

Comment: /mnt folder exist in / partition  <br/> Problem is sdb1 or sdc1 whatever mount points for usb is not creating under /mnt

Comment: Please update your question with that information, to me it sounds like /mnt doesn't exist. Though the same is true if you mean the mount points. Make it read write. then make the /mnt/whatever, reboot.  Please include your fstab in your question edit.